# Why jquery toggle() doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, toggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.a').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('.tablex').eq(index).toggle();
});
});
```

There are 8 .a's and 8 .tablex.

```
<div class="a">X</div>
<div class="tablex">...</div>
<div class="a">X</div>
<div class="tablex">...</div>
<div class="a">X</div>
<div class="tablex">...</div>
...
```

Only first one toggles when I click X.
When I click 2nd div the 4th tablex toggles.

Why could this be happening ?

I changed it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
});
```

It worked thanks Josh Crazier.

Comment: Why is there a period in the class attribute ?

Comment: @adeneo i dont know jquery well. i look w3schools pages when i need something but i couldnt do it this time.

Comment: Unless the HTML differs, it sounds like you just want `$(this).next().toggle();`.

Comment: @adeneo i misswrited it sorry. edited now.

Comment: @JoshCrozier wow thank you it worked! I would upvote if i had 15 rep. Why my code wasnt working?

Comment: If you go for index, it should be $( ".a" ).index( this )  - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwMXdV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because `$(this).index()` isn't just counting the other elements with the same class. It's getting the position of the element among all its siblings. So when you click on the first `.a`, `index = 0`; when you click on the second `.a`, `index = 2`, the third one is `index = 4`, and so on.

You can use `$(this).parent.find(".a").index(this)` to get its index just among the other `.a` elements.

But simpler is just

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```